# SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()

Tags: android

Вопрос новичка.

Есть счетчик, и данные сохраняются с помощью SharedPreferences.

Нужно повесить кнопку, для сброса данных. Как можно это осуществить?

Answer (score 1):

Удалить *SharedPreferences* файл либо записать значение счетчика 0. Понятно, что при удалении файла сбросятся и все остальные хранящиеся в нем параметры.

##### `ResetCounterActivity.java`

```
public class ResetCounterActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "counter"; // Имя файла, где хранится счетчик

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_counter);
    }

    public void onResetCounterClicked(View view) {
        getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME,0).edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

##### `activity_reset_counter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset counter"
        android:onClick="onResetCounterClicked"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но нужно, чтобы данные сохранялись. Но была возможность их в любой момент обнулить/стереть.